# Preg_Match section of url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to match a url that can be inputted a few ways.

The url is an iTunes link, and I'm trying to source the `id` out of the url.

I want to know is it possible to have an expression strip everything but the `id#########` and then use `str_replace` to remove the id.

I have started here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dWp but am no expert in expressions.

The main point to the above url is that if it is already stripped from the iTunes url and the id, is there a way to store it in the array?

Or is there a way to say:

```
if( THE STRING IS NOT EMPTY ) {
    if( THERE ARE MATCHES IN THE PREG_MATCH ) { $VAR = $MATCHES; }
    if( THERE ARE NO MATCHES IN THE PREG_MATCH ) { $VAR = $ORIGINAL_STRING; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a regex since there a PHP function to parse URLs (`parse_url`) and since you already know that there's an id in the last directory of the url (in other words, you don't need to check the format):

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$lastdir = array_pop(explode('/', $path));
$result = ltrim($lastdir, 'id');
```

[demo](https://eval.in/484823)

Comment: Geez I'm such an idiot! I totally forgot about `parse_url`

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provided a URL example, but... it sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
$subject = 'http://foo.bar/baz/id1234567890/yah';
$pattern = '/id(\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

If you used print_r to display the array in this case:

```
print_r($matches);
```

It would show this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id1234567890
    [1] => 1234567890
)
```